# How to compiler find the right implicit?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-cats, type-level-computation

I am trying to understand type level programming in Scala with the help of this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qwUYqv6lKtQ.
Let's consider the provided code:

```
trait Nat
class _0 extends Nat
class Succ[A <: Nat] extends Nat

type _1 = Succ[_0]
type _2 = Succ[_1] // = Succ[Succ[_0]]
type _3 = Succ[_2] // = Succ[Succ[Succ[_0]]]
type _4 = Succ[_3] // ... and so on
type _5 = Succ[_4]

sealed trait <[A <: Nat, B <: Nat]
object < {
    def apply[A <: Nat, B <: Nat](implicit lt: <[A, B]): <[A, B] = lt
    implicit def ltBasic[B <: Nat]: <[_0, Succ[B]] = new <[_0, Succ[B]] {}
    implicit def inductive[A <: Nat, B <: Nat](implicit lt: <[A, B]): <[Succ[A], Succ[B]] = new <[Succ[A], Succ[B]] {}
}

sealed trait <=[A <: Nat, B <: Nat]
object <= {
    def apply[A <: Nat, B <: Nat](implicit lte: <=[A, B]): <=[A, B] = lte
    implicit def lteBasic[B <: Nat]: <=[_0, B] = new <=[_0, B] {}
    implicit def inductive[A <: Nat, B <: Nat](implicit lt: <=[A, B]): <=[Succ[A], Succ[B]] = new <=[Succ[A], Succ[B]] {}
}
```

The author describes the compile steps for the definition `val invalidComparison: _3 < _2 = <[_3, _2]`:

1. the `apply` method needs an implicit instance of `<[_2, _3]`
2. to find that instance, the compiler can choose to run any of the two
   implicit methods - it will attempt to call the `inductive` method, but
   it will need an implicit instance of `<[_1, _2]`
3. in the same way, the compiler marks that it can call the `inductive`
   method, but it needs an implicit instance of type `<[_0, _1]`
4. in this case, the method signature of `ltBasic` signals that the
   compiler can build an instance of `<[_0, _1]` because `_1 = Succ[0]`
5. now, given an instance of `<[_0, _1]` the compiler can build an
   instance of `<[_1, _2]`
6. in the same style, given an instance of `<[_1, _2]` the compiler can
   build an instance of `<[_2, _3]`
7. given the instance of `<[_2, _3]`, it can safely be passed to the
   `apply` method and returned

The question is, where the compiler knows how to decrement `<[_2, _3]` until it hits `<[_0, _1]` to get right implicits?

Given the instance of `<[_0, _1]` the compiler can build an instance of `<[_1, _2]`, how the compiler knows that?

Comment: You can solve this by hand, with a very mechanical approach which is the same one the compiler does. You need `_2 < _3`, you have two options `_0 < Succ[B]`, in this case it doesn't apply because `_2 =!= _0` and `Succ[A] < Succ[B]` if `A < B` so _2 < _3` if `_1 < _2` and it continues down until it reach `_0 < Succ[_0]` so everything resolves.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't "decrement" anything. It just knows that `inductive` can find the right implicit if it has the right implicit parameters. It doesn't know it'll find those yet, but it'll try anyway.

> Given the instance of `<[_0, _1]` the compiler can build an instance of `<[_1, _2]`, how the compiler knows that?

From the method signature of `inductive`:

```
implicit def inductive[A <: Nat, B <: Nat](implicit lt: <[A, B]): <[Succ[A], Succ[B]]
```

It says that it will provide a value of type `<[Succ[A], Succ[B]]` if it's given an implicit `<[A, B]`. -- The looked for type `<[_1, _2]` is the same as type `<Succ[_0], Succ[_1]`, so it'll need an implicit `<[_0, _1]` for that. Then it'll start looking for that.

It doesn't know it decremented anything, it just went searching for the implicit it needs and the implicit it needs to find them.